# Labels for each bin in geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have the following histogram:

```r
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color="black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, by = 0.5) + 0.25)
```

I want it to show the count of each bin as the label above each bar.

i tried this:

```r
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) +
 geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "black") +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, by = 0.5) + 0.25) +
 geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count..), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

But it just generated a mess (image attached). What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `stat_bin` so that you can also specify the same `binwidth` for the text as for the histogram:

```r
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, by = 0.5) + 0.25) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=0.5, geom='text',
           aes(label=after_stat(count)),
           vjust = 0)
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use `position_nudge`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "black", fill = "white") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, by = 0.5)) +
  stat_bin(binwidth = 0.5, geom = "text", aes(label = ..count..),
           position = position_nudge(y = 500), color = "black") +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "Histogram of Diamond Carat Weight",
       x = "Carat Weight (ct)",
       y = "Count")
```

[image]